# Manipulating input shared between buffers

Tags: c, multithreading, process, operating-system, buffer

I'm trying to solve a problem in my Operating Systems class. For my project, I have to solve a simplified Conway's problem using constant size buffers and lightweight threads. The program reads a stream of characters, packages the stream into 10-character blocks, and write them as 24-character lines. The pound sign ('#') character is used as an end-of-data sentinel value. We have to implement the following 2 changes: after every block an extra blank is inserted, and every adjacent pair of asterisks is replaced by an exclamation point. Asterisks are considered adjacent only if they are in the same block.

I have declared my global constants and buffer sizes and have to use the buffer operations `sbuf_insert` and `sbuf_remove` included.

```
/* Global constants */
const int BLOCKMAX=10;      /* Length of input "blocks" */
const int LINEMAX=24;       /* Length of output "lines" */
const char EODsentinel='#'; /* End-Of-Data Sentinel value */
int rdbufsize = 4;    /* buffer size between ReadInput and Squash   */
int prbufsize = 7;    /* buffer size between Squash and PrintOutput */
```

As of know, I have only set up the buffers to pass input between threads. This is my first venture into C and I am struggling. The threads are set up and working. I have all the input printing, I am just unsure how to manipulate the input using the buffers. Here are my 3 routines.

```
/* ReadInput thread routine */
void* ReadInput(void * vargp)
{
    char ch;
    char newline;
    scanf("%c%c", &ch, &newline);
    while (ch != EODsentinel)
    {
        sbuf_insert(&rdbuf, ch);
        scanf("%c%c", &ch, &newline);
    }
    sbuf_insert(&rdbuf, EODsentinel);
    return NULL;
    }

/* Squash thread routine */
void* Squash(void * vargp)
{
    char ch;
    ch = sbuf_remove(&rdbuf);
    while (ch != EODsentinel)
    {
        sbuf_insert(&prbuf, ch);
        ch = sbuf_remove(&rdbuf);
    }
    sbuf_insert(&prbuf, EODsentinel);
    return NULL;
}

/* PrintOutput thread routine */
void* PrintOutput(void * vargp)
{
    char ch;
    ch = sbuf_remove(&prbuf);
    while (ch != EODsentinel)
    {
        printf("%c", ch);
        ch = sbuf_remove(&prbuf);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return NULL;
}
```

I know what I need to do but am unsure how to do it. I need to add the line break logic to `PrintOutput`, add the space adding logic to `ReadInput`, and add the asterisk exclamation logic to `Squash`. Any guidance is appreciated.